# Two separate forms leading to same destination, is there a way to separate methods calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, ejs

I am trying to develop an express app and I have a login page, a signup page and a display page, both sign up and login pages lead to display page where it simply displays the username but I was wondering if there is a way I can differentiate between two calls that are made from signup and login page to display page. I'll try to explain with code shown below.

`app.js` code below

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var bod = require("body-parser");
app.use(bod.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});

app.post("/bioform",function(req,res){
    var userName = req.body.username;

    console.log(req.body);
    res.render("bioform",{userName:userName});

});

app.get("/signup", function(req, res) {
    res.render("signup");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server started");
});
```

`home.ejs` file below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mitr:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/biodata.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-around" id="navbar-home" href="/">Home</a>
        <div class="ml-auto" id="navbar-joint">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logout</a>
       </div>
  </nav>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
   <form action="/bioform" method="POST">
    <h2 class="d-flex justify-content-center">LOGIN</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <a href="../views/boot-2.html" class="d-flex justify-content-end">New User</a>
</form>

  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`signup.ejs` code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mitr:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/biodata.css">
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-around" id="navbar-home" href="/">Home</a>
        <div class="ml-auto" id="navbar-joint">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logout</a>
       </div>
  </nav>

<div class="card" id="signup-card">
  <div class="card-body" id="signup-card-body">
   <form action="/bioform" method="POST">
    <h3 class="d-flex justify-content-center">SIGN UP</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
     </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="confirminputPassword" name="confirminputPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" name="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">I agree</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`bioform.ejs` code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mitr:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/biodata.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-around" id="navbar-home" href="/">Home</a>
        <div class="ml-auto" id="navbar-joint">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logout</a>
       </div>
  </nav>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">

    <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center text-success">Welcome!!!  <%= userName%></h1>


  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am calling the following method in `app.js` from both `home.ejs` and `signup.ejs`,

```
app.post("/bioform",function(req,res){
    var userName = req.body.username;

    console.log(req.body);
    res.render("bioform",{userName:userName});

});
```

Is there a way I can separate these two calls to same method from two different pages? Will deeply appreciate your input on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's problem in creating  two different routes  `/login` , `/register`? ...and redirect to `/biofrom` after, if successfully logged in or signed up.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following this way as your register form has email field and login form has not this field. So in register request email is defined as if part will run other wise else will be run. But i will suggest you to make two routes for this issue.

```
app.post("/bioform",function(req,res){
    let email = req.body.email;
    if (!!email) {
        // Register.ejs request
        // Your registration process can be done here 
    }else{
        // home.ejs request
        // Your login process can be done here 
    } 
    // var userName = req.body.username;
    // res.render("bioform",{userName:userName});

});
```